# Select an element random from array, but which is not selected by user at that time

Tags: php, arrays, random

In an array select element randomly, but which is not selected by user

For example : `array('02', '11', '20')` , if user selects one element (`'02'`) then we want to select an element randomly either `'11'` or `'20'`. i.e user select `'02'` will get `'11'` on one time  and `'20'` on other time.

It is a long array ,so IF/ELSE etc are not pratically possible.

Comment: You could first remove the value the user has selected and then return a random element from the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function unique_rand($array, $value) {
    unset($array[array_search($value,$array)]); // delete user-selected item
    return $array[array_rand($array, 1)];
}
```